# postgresql database didn't restored in ubuntu and got blank

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql, pg-restore

i try to restore databse form my pc(windows) that i send it from pscp

i use this script :

```
sudo -u postgres pg_restore -U postgres -f /home/abura/first_backup.sql
```

and got blank, so i randomly click to get it back normal(ctrl+v)

here is the terminal image [image: before randomly click]

when i check inside postgresql, there is not database i looking for

SOLVED,though i'm not sure what is the problem 
i try to backup database with different format(plain),(before:custom) 
i try different code and finally error appear. 
and it solved with this code
`sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres -d dbase_tsunami -f backupdatabase.sql`

Comment: Read the error message it tells you the problem. Then go here [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) for usage info.

Comment: First solve the sudo problem. Then come back here.